# RA-01 Lora Radio not turning off

Tags: esp8266

am trying to completly turn off ra-01 radio and esp8266 and turn it on by external trigger but i have issues getting the lora radio to turn off

```
#include <LoRa.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // while (!Serial);  

  // disable wifi
  WiFi.mode( WIFI_OFF );
  WiFi.forceSleepBegin();

  // LoRa
  #define dio0 2
  #define ss 15
  #define rst 16
  //#define rst 32

  LoRa.setPins(ss, rst, dio0);
  LoRa.setSyncWord(0xF3);
  
  Serial.println("LoRa: OK");

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("LoRa: Fail!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Sending packet: ");

  // send packet
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("c");
  LoRa.endPacket();
  LoRa.end();

  // shutdown spi
  SPI.end();
  digitalWrite(dio0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ss, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rst, HIGH);
  
  // deep sleep
  ESP.deepSleep(0); 
}

void loop() {

}``
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Turning off Lora Radio?

Comment: "but i have issues getting the lora radio to turn off" So how do you notice that you have a problem with it? Sleep current too high? Any more details available?